# How do I filter a column with a keyword list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a total of three columns:

1. Item Descriptions
2. Accepted Keywords
3. Unaccepted Keywords

As the name sort of suggests, the Item Descriptions column is filled with descriptions for items. However, there are a lot of irrelevant items that I need to filter out. And unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible with the built-in filtering tools.

I was looking to fill in a fourth column with a filtered version of Item Descriptions. It would include all descriptions where a string from Accepted Keywords is present, but exclude all descriptions where a Unaccepted Keyword is present. This is even if a row includes an Accepted Keyword.

What is the best way of going about this? I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Probably a helper column using `FIND` or `SEARCH`.

Comment: How strict do you want this to be? I mean a discription of "Back to the USSR" would technically **not** include the *accepted* keyword "US". But if you'd allow for the string to be a substring of another word then it becomes fine >> "**US**SR". I hope this makes sense? Either way, I think you should focus on some sample data with some of these edge-cases and update your question including this data *and* the expected results.

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would help to help you - best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` method as a custom `LAMBDA()` function, which can either be defined and used directly within `LET()` or defined in Name Manager and used throughout the workbook.

**Example 1:** Defined and used directly within `LET()`

```
=LET(LIKE, LAMBDA(array,criteria,
   BYROW(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(criteria, 1), array)), LAMBDA(r, SUM(r)))),
FILTER(Table1, LIKE(Table1[Item], Table2[Include]) * NOT(LIKE(Table1[Item], Table2[Exclude])), "No records found"))
```

**Example 2:** Defined in Name Manager

**(1)** Open Name Manager (Ctrl+F3) and define a new name called `LIKE` with the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(array,criteria, BYROW(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(criteria, 1), array)), LAMBDA(r, SUM(r))))
```

**(2)** Use the `LIKE()` function to write include/exclude criteria for the `FILTER()` function as follows:

```
=FILTER(Table1, LIKE(Table1[Item], Table2[Include]) * NOT(LIKE(Table1[Item], Table2[Exclude])), "No records found")
```

**Note:** in both of the examples shown above, `Table1` contains the items to be filtered, and `Table2` contains the keywords to be included/excluded in two separate columns.

**Sample Results:**

[image: like_function.png]

Answer (score 1):

Even though OP has not yet provided a full example. I wanted to share an option to filter based on strict matching using the newly introduced `PY()` function:
[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=PY(
    import re
    [s for s in xl("A2:A7")[0] if re.match(r'(?i).*\b(?:'+'|'.join(xl("B2:B5")[0])+r')\b.*', s) and not re.match(r'(?i).*\b(?:'+'|'.join(xl("C2:C3")[0])+r')\b.*', s)]
)
```

For those who don't want to concatenate all (un)accepted keywords, you could run two list comprenehsions within the initial one:

```
=PY(
    import re
    [s for s in xl("A2:A7")[0] if any([re.match(fr'(?i).*\b{x}\b.*', s) for x in xl("B2:B5")[0]]) and not any([re.match(fr'(?i).*\b{x}\b.*', s) for x in xl("C2:C3")[0]])]
)
```

**Note**: Both options are currently case-insensitive. Remove the "(?i)" part from the expressions if you desire case-sensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `FILTER` and checking each row to ensure it does or does not include the items in the second and third columns. The formula gets messy, so I tried to clean it up using the `LET` function.

```
=LET(
    descriptions, <range of descriptions>,
    accepted, <range of accepted keywords (excluding blanks)>,
    unaccepted, <range of unaccepted keywords (excluding blanks)>,
    FILTER(descriptions,
        MMULT(N(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(accepted), descriptions)))), SEQUENCE(ROWS(accepted),,,0)) *
        NOT(MMULT(N(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(unaccepted), descriptions)))), SEQUENCE(ROWS(unaccepted),,,0)))))
```

**Explanation**

Assign the relevant ranges to the first three variables in `LET`. It is important  not to include any blanks, since an empty string will always match to another string. The second argument to `FILTER` uses `*` as an element-wise `AND`, where it checks that (at least) one of the accepted keywords was found AND none of the unaccepted keywords was found. This was the functionality I inferred from your post.

Each of the conditions creates 2-dimensional array where each row represents the position of each keyword in the description or an error if that keyword was not found. `N(NOT(ISERROR()))` converts these to numeric values, 1 if found and 0 is not found. `MMULT` against a sequence of 1s adds up the number of matches, and multiplying the two conditions together results in 0 if either condition is false and a number greater than 0 if both are true. `FILTER` treats the 0s as `FALSE` and everything else as `TRUE`.

As was mentioned in the comments, this will match even if the keyword is part of a substring, so be aware of that. Also, this version is not case-sensitive. To make it case-sensitive, replace `SEARCH` with `FIND`.